# Number of MKL threads not affecting performance of numpy mean

Tags: python, numpy, intel-mkl

I am trying to optimize the number of MKL library threads that are used when a call is made to `numpy.mean()` (I am using numpy that has been built against the MKL library). The number of threads can be dynamically controlled at runtime using `mkl.set_num_threads(n)` from the [mkl-service](https://docs.anaconda.com/mkl-service/) library. While this does correctly set the number of threads, and in-fact this is verified in the CPU usage with `htop`, I am bewildered to find that it doesn't have any impact on the runtime. Consider this trial code where `tmp` is a (12, 384, 320) array:

```
for j in range(1000):
    out = np.mean(tmp, axis=(0))
```

With a single thread this takes up roughly 21 seconds and it takes up the same amount if I use a greater number of threads. The CPU consumption does go up with more threads, but there is no performance improvement. I also verified this issue by averaging over the last dimension to make the averaging more cache efficient.

Any ideas on why this might be happening?

Comment: a) if you can avoid using loops in python - do it. vectorizing your code makes it much faster.
b) are you sure that your numpy build is aware of MKL installed? I use numpy built with icc (and MKL obviously) and I had to increase the number of iterations by 3 (!) orders of magnitude to get a comparable single-thread result -- about 6 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

MKL Summary Statistics functions work in 1 thread in the case of such small input problem sizes. The threading will be switch on when the problem size >~ 10 K elements.

Comment: Interesting, is there a reference you can provide? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Unfortunately, this topic has not been documented anywhere. It should be add into one of the next coming versions.